# extract match and different from 2 huge text files

Tags: linux

I have 2 large text files

```
file1:
aaa@email.com
bbb@email.com
ccc@email.com
ddd@email.com
...

file2:
abc@email.com
bbb@email.com
cnd@email.com
sds@email.com
...
```

I want to display the following:

1. Match email between file1 and file2 to file3
2. non-match email in file1 to file4
3. non-match email in file2 in file5

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort` and `join`. See bash example below that takes advantage of process substitution

```
join -o 1.1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file3
join -o 1.1 -v 1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file4
join -o 2.1 -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file5
```

Comment: not sure if i did something wrong, the output file3 display empty (zerobyte) while i check manually, there are some match thought

Comment: @user2522209, do your input files contain email addresses one-per-line, with no  spaces?

Comment: Careful with `join` and `sort` and locales.  The correct way to call `sort` on a file is `LC_ALL=C sort myfile`.  Locales like `en_US` with insane sort orders are going to give you a hard time otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming file1 and file2 are both sorted:

```
comm -12 file1 file2 > file3
comm -23 file1 file2 > file4
comm -13 file1 file2 > file5
```

Assuming they're not sorted and you're using `bash`:

```
comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file3
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file4
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, using `comm` instead. `comm` wants it's input to be sorted, so you can either sort the files beforehand (most efficient), or on the fly. If the files are sorted,

```
comm -12 file1 file2 > file3
```

will give you the lines common to both `file1` and `file2`, and put them in `file3`. If they are not sorted (and can't be for some reason), use this version to provide sorted input to `comm` without changing the files:

```
comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file3
```

For the other requirements, either:

```
comm -23 file1 file2 > file4
comm -13 file1 file2 > file5
```

or

```
comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file4
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > file5
```

Answer (score 0):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$0]++;
    next
} 
($0 in a) {
    delete a[$0]; 
    print > "file3";
    next
} 
!($0 in a) {
    print > "file4";
    next
} 
END {
    for (x in a) 
        print x > "file5"
}' file1 file2
```

#### Test:

```
$ head file*
==> file1 <==
aa@email.com
bbb@email.com
ccc@email.com
ddd@email.com

==> file2 <==
abc@email.com
bbb@email.com
cnd@email.com
sds@email.com

$ awk '
> NR==FNR {
>     a[$0]++;
>     next
> } 
> ($0 in a) {
>     delete a[$0]; 
>     print > "file3";
>     next
> } 
> !($0 in a) {
>     print > "file4";
>     next
> } 
> END {
>     for (x in a) 
>         print x > "file5"
> }' file1 file2

$ head file*
==> file1 <==
aa@email.com
bbb@email.com
ccc@email.com
ddd@email.com

==> file2 <==
abc@email.com
bbb@email.com
cnd@email.com
sds@email.com

==> file3 <==
bbb@email.com

==> file4 <==
abc@email.com
cnd@email.com
sds@email.com

==> file5 <==
ccc@email.com
aa@email.com
ddd@email.com
```